# Error when create a new version update of iOS app to iTunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I was successfully updated my app to 1.1 , But when I am going to update my app again then it showing the popup to update the paid application schedule .

But I am using only free app , is there any way to without adding the account details update the version?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it will not ask you to enter your bank details. It just asks you to agree on the new Paid application agreement.

Go to the Agreements, Tax, and Banking link and there is a new Paid Appliction agreement at the top, agree to that and you will be able to proceed.

More info here: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deva001f4a14

This is the only part, that should be followed: 
[image: see image]

Adding bank information etc is different thing, when you have in-App Purchases and wants to get the funds, you will have to provide the bank info.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No there no agreement on the top of the Agreement,tax banking tab .... thats why I post it here...

Comment: Please follow the link in my updated answer to proceed. Itunes Connect is now App Store Connect.

Comment: I am not asking for the adding account and more details... I know if client ready to add the account then It will work .... I need another way ...Without  adding the account .

Comment: In the Request Contracts section, find the agreement you want to sign and on the right, click Request. Please check the updates, that helps